# Why is there no type mismatch error?

Tags: go

I define the number to be input by user as `var input float64` and I input an integer and I would expect to get an error but I get `err = <nil>`. What am I missing?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var input float64 

    fmt.Print("Enter a number:")

    n, err := fmt.Scanf("%f\n", &input)

    fmt.Printf("err = %v\n", err)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v is not a float - exiting with error\n", input, err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("n is %v:", n)
}
```

This is the output:

```
C:\Go\src\play\exercise>go run exercise2.go
Enter a number to take its square root: 1
err = <nil>
n is 1:
```

Comment: You know that 1 is a perfectly valid floating point number?

Comment: No, I did not know. I thought that floating point numbers need to be written with a decimal. The way I was thinking, `1.0` should not given an error but `1` should. For instance, in Mark Summerfield's book on Go, "floating-point numbers are written with a decimal point..."

Comment: I think that what @FUZxxl was trying to say is that "1" is perfectly representable as a floating point number, namely `1.0`. The `%f` format should read floating point numbers containing a decimal point. This is probably a convenience thing, because people might not want to type "1.0" if all the need is "1", but I'd be interested in a more complete answer containing actual evidence ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Go Programming Language Specification
>
> [Conversions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)
>
> Specific rules apply to (non-constant) conversions between numeric
>   types.
>
> Conversions between numeric types
>
> For the conversion of non-constant numeric values, the following rules
>   apply:
>
> 1. When converting between integer types, if the value is a signed
>      integer, it is sign extended to implicit infinite precision;
>      otherwise it is zero extended. It is then truncated to fit in the
>      result type's size. For example, if v := uint16(0x10F0), then
>      uint32(int8(v)) == 0xFFFFFFF0. The conversion always yields a valid
>      value; there is no indication of overflow.
> 2. When converting a floating-point number to an integer, the fraction
>      is discarded (truncation towards zero).
> 3. When converting an integer or floating-point number to a
>      floating-point type, or a complex number to another complex type,
>      the result value is rounded to the precision specified by the
>      destination type. For instance, the value of a variable x of type
>      float32 may be stored using additional precision beyond that of an
>      IEEE-754 32-bit number, but float32(x) represents the result of
>      rounding x's value to 32-bit precision. Similarly, x + 0.1 may use
>      more than 32 bits of precision, but float32(x + 0.1) does not.
>
> In all non-constant conversions involving floating-point or complex
>   values, if the result type cannot represent the value the conversion
>   succeeds but the result value is implementation-dependent.

In Go, you can convert from an integer type to a floating-point type. Therefore, there is no reason not to be forgiving.

> [Robustness principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle)
>
> In computing, the robustness principle is a general design guideline
>   for software:
>
> Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others
>   (often reworded as "Be conservative in what you send, be
>   liberal in what you accept").
>
> The principle is also known as Postel's law, after Internet pioneer
>   Jon Postel, who wrote in an early specification of the Transmission
>   Control Protocol that:[1](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)
>
> TCP implementations should follow a general principle of robustness: be conservative in > what you do, be liberal in what you
>   accept from others.
>
> In other words, code that sends commands or data to other machines (or
>   to other programs on the same machine) should conform completely to
>   the specifications, but code that receives input should accept
>   non-conformant input as long as the meaning is clear.

Comment: and just for completeness here another link from golang specification: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Floating-point_literals

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question

Answer (score 1):

> Scanf scans text read from standard input, storing successive space-separated values into successive arguments as determined by the format. **It returns the number of items successfully scanned.**

Scanf returns the number of things it read. In this case n == 1 because... you entered one token followed by a newline. Presumably, you want the value of `input`, not `n`.